# WindowsForms_exeption

Tags: textbox

в  textbox  дает  nullreferenceexception  как обработать его что бы мог внести дани в textbox,значение value получаю без проблем а вот при присвоении дает  expetion

```
  public Form4(object value)
    {

     this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Form4(object value)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: спасибо но в этом случае форма не открывается?

Comment: спасибо Dmitry,уже нашел проблему